# Suppressing PHP undefined variable messages?

Tags: php

When I developed a website on my localserver it was working fine.

Now that I've uploaded it live I'm getting several notices.

Notice: Undefined index: ... on line 14

I've figured out that it happens because I'm using variables which arn't defined, and would like to go through and fix it. But I need a live version working tonight.

Is it possible to suppress the Notices and have the website act as it does on my localhost while its on my live server?

Comment: "... as it does on my localhost ..." WHOOPS.

Comment: You should never suppress anything AND you should never show any errors/notices on a live site EVER! So I don't see the problem, you'll have to fix this anyways!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can choose which kind of errors will show up on your site on a global scale through php.ini or through .htaccess for specific folders, or per script by using `error_reporting()`.

Read more on that and which options to set for your specific needs at [www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php)

Also read: http://www.php.net/error-reporting

Answer (score 9):

You've got it twice wrong. On your localhost and on your live server!

#### Localhost

- Always show everything on screen, you want to know about notices too before you go live, as you can see now!

#### Live server

- Never show anything on screen, it makes you vulnerable (it's deadly)
- Log everything, also notices! So don't do what the other answers tell you!

Answer (score 4):

Look in the file `php.ini` for a line similar to `error_reporting = E_STRICT` - Edit it to remove the STRICT bit and put in `error_reporting = E_ERROR`.

I would recommend that in the near future that you fix those errors anyway.