# Understanding PHP Strict - why should I care?

Tags: php, error-handling

In a [recent question I posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7670727/suppressing-php-undefined-variable-messages) I describe how I developed a site on my local server and everything was working fine. Then after deploying it live I was getting errors because of the use of undefined variables. Mainly due to situations like the following...

```
if($var!=""){...}
```

I know I should use PHP strict and fix all of the errors based on the responses I got on my last question.

Now I want to know... why? What vulnerabilities may be created by leaving such code? I want to be able to justify to others why the errors need to be fixed.

Comment: You'll find a lot of helpful reasons by going through similar questions/answers http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D+strict+errors

Comment: Using an undefined variable is an `E_NOTICE`, not `E_STRICT`, right? Strict messages are similar to notices, but tend to be more for things that will change in the future, or are more "nitpicky" than notices.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The purpose of `E_STRICT` messages is:

> to have PHP suggest changes to your code which will ensure the best interoperability and forward compatibility of your code.

<sup>Source: [Error Handling Constants](http://php.net/errorfunc.constants#errorfunc.constants.errorlevels.e-strict)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

In this case, it's because the behaviour won't be predictable.

If your variable is not defined, your condition could be true or wrong, randomly.

Comment: Actually it's predictable. But coders are still supposed to define variables by giving them values. http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php

Answer (score 0):

```
if (isset($var) and $var != "")
```

or:

```
if(strlen($var) > 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Reminder isset function accept multiple variable while empty does not.

```
if(isset($var_1, $var_2) && !empty($var_1) && !empty($var_2)){
  // code
}
```